# Keeping client state when an api with mocha

Tags: node.js, testing, mocha.js

My api can be asked to create an object, then later asked to update that same object, so my test file does this...

```
var foobarId;  // this might be a mistake

it("should create a single foobar", function(done) {
    server
        .post("/foobar?key=value")
        .expect("Content-type", /json/)
        .expect(200)
        .end(function(err, res) {
            res.status.should.equal(200);
            res.body.should.have.property('key', 'value');
            foobarId = res.body._id;
        done();
    });
});

it("should return a foobar when I get one", function(done) {
    server
        .get("/foobar/" + foobarId)
        .expect("Content-type", /json/)
        .expect(200)
        .end(function(err, res) {
            res.status.should.equal(200);
            res.body.should.have.property('key', 'value');
        done();
    });
});
```

So is this wrong what I'm trying here?  (1) as I get more logic into the test, I risk creating logic errors in the test and needing a test for my test.  (2) when the create fails, my console output gets ugly... first, the assertion error that I expect and need telling me the test failed, but then ugly traceback stuff, I think, because `foobarId` is undefined.

The ugliness makes me think that the good people at mocha (or supertest or wherever) didn't expect me to do what I'm doing.

Is there a right way to write this kind of test?

Comment: You should always make tests independent from each other. I would make one test out of the two you have, and "get" the foobar inside the `end` function.

Comment: Thanks @migg, but I have a whole series of things to check for the new object, including a PUT and then a GET to see that the PUT worked.  Wouldn't that become one long, nested test, which would be bad also, right?

Comment: Wouldn't the PUT+GET be one additional independent test?

Comment: @migg, yes, I'd like PUT+GET to be an independent test, but PUT needs the object id from the POST (create)

Comment: Then you should consider using `beforeEach` to setup every test with a POST and store the ID on each test making them independent.